# Adding subview in xcode hides rest of the view

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to add a subview programmatically to my view, `FirstViewController.xib`. For now this is how it looks like

[image]

When I click on the compose button another view, `SecondViewController.xib`, pops up from the bottom. It has a navigation bar similar to what you see in the picture.

No I want to add a subview:

```
TTMessageController* controller = [[[TTMessageController alloc] 
                                 initWithRecipients:nil] autorelease];

[self.view addSubview:controller.view]
```

However I get a strange result. The `controller.view` is overlapping the sidebar:

[image]

How can I solve that problem so that the navigation bar is visible.

Comment: Watch that "autorelease". You're adding the view as a subview, so the retain count for the view increases by 1, but not the retain count for the TTMessageController. Don't release that controller until you've removed TTMessageController's view from its superview.

Comment: I am new to iOS dev, what does that mean for me? Do I have to remove the autorelease?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a UIViewController's (or subclasses') view to another UIView isn't how Apple recommend you present view controller's views -- it means things like orientation change detection can misbehave, etc. Apple say that you shouldn't have more than one view controller responsible for any one 'screen' of content.

The usual way to present the standard mail controller interace is by presenting it as you would a normal UIViewController (e.g. modally, or pushing on a nav stack, etc.) -- and I suggest that the same advice goes for the Three20 mail composer too.

The advice I give in my answer here is related:

[iPhone, Obj-C, How can I use in app email from an actionsheet button click while using addSubview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110034/iphone-obj-c-how-can-i-use-in-app-email-from-an-actionsheet-button-click-while/5111291#5111291)

Comment: +1--OP almost certainly means to be presenting this TTMessageController modally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the frame of the subview down:

```
CGRect frame = controller.view.frame;
frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
controller.view.frame = frame;
```

The `40` value above is the y-value of the view's origin and should be adjusted accordingly to suit your needs.