# Xcode Interface Builder separate ViewController to control a subview

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, viewcontroller

I have a View controlled by WorkController (derived from UIViewController)
On the view I have a subview myCollection of type UICollectionView

Due to complexity of handling the collection I created a separate controller MyCollectionController.

How do I (in Interface Builder, XCode 4.5 ) set my subview's controller to MyCollectionController ? I also need to set the delegate and the source.

I did not find a way to do it in Interface Builder so now I just do it programmatically.

On `viewDidLoad` of the WorkController I create an instance of MyController and set all connection between it and the myCollectionView.

But how to do it with IB ?

thanks

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110034/iphone-obj-c-how-can-i-use-in-app-email-from-an-actionsheet-button-click-while/5111291#5111291). It says Apple does not recommend doing it. What would be the preferable way to achieve what I need ? I still want this code to be separated ( one of the reasons - I want to reuse it on other screens ) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider leaving `WorkController` as the view controller for the subview so that you can create connections easily in IB and obtain an IBOutlet reference to the subview.  Then, when the view loads, you can have `WorkController` create a separate object (NSObject subclass) that serves as the data source and delegate for your `UICollectionView`.

The benefit of this is that your view controller manages the whole display, as Apple suggests, while employing a reusable object to off-load some of the view management.

Comment: Thanks. Being just re-writing my code this way. I wonder if it would be possible to create an IB plugin that would allow me to do the connection in the design time and somehow instantiate those custom delegate and source objects ...

Comment: Phillip, I just had an idea : if I have a subclass of UICollectionView ( MyViewClass ) - can this class incapsulate also the delegate and the source ? This way it will be much easier , I think

Comment: You have to consider that you're then creating a new view with those particular behaviors having fixed definitions (in the subclass).  This makes the view slightly less configurable but, if that doesn't matter to your purposes, it should work.